# Jquery Replace function not working properly in ie7 and ie 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Raduio buttons with Labeles associated with that.

```
<div id="dependents">
    <input ng-non-bindable  type="radio" id='Partner' name="relationship" class="dependent-relation" value='P' />
    <label for="Partner">Prtner</label>

    <input ng-non-bindable  type="radio" id='Child' name="relationship" class="dependent-relation" value='C' />

    <label for="Child">Child</label>
</div>
```

Above div will be added dynamically to the page. We can have multiple dependants.

So every time while appending this div, i'm changing the `Id, name` of Radio button along with `for` label. Below is the script i'm trying to replace.

```
var html = htmlContent; // html content will be above code
html = html.replace('Partner', 'Partner' + count); // Replacing Id : Working fine
html = html.replace('for="Partner"', 'for="Partner' + count + '"'); // Replacing for : Not working
html = html.replace('Child', 'Child' + count); // Replacing Id : Working fine
html = html.replace('for="Child"', 'for="Child' + count + '"'); // Replacing for : Not working
```

This is working perfect in IE9, IE 10, chrome, but its not working IE7 and IE8.

Can any one help me on this?

I have found the problem...

I think whenever i tried to replace like this

```
html = html.replace('name="relationship"', 'name="relationship"' + count + '"');
```

its not working(only in IE 8 & 7). Any suggestion???

Comment: You see errors on IE7/8 Console?? Click F12 to see.

Comment: your html string mixes double quotes and single quotes `value='P'` and `value='c'` . You need to espace some

Comment: `replace` is just JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: no error is showing in console

Comment: you should remove the double quote after relationship in `, 'name="relationship"' + count + '"'`

Answer (score 0):

the reason it does not work is because before you are replacing the same word.

Try with:

```
var html = "<div id="Dependents"> ... </div>";
html = html.replace('for="Partner"', 'for="Partner2' + count + '"');
html = html.replace('Partner', 'Partner' + count); 
html = html.replace('Partner2', 'Partner');
html = html.replace('for="Child"', 'for="Child2' + count + '"');
html = html.replace('Child', 'Child' + count);
html = html.replace('Child2', 'Child');
```

Comment: i found the problem, wherever i have string like name="relationship", its not working